# CapSize for a customized errorbar plot

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, matlab-figure

I am writing a customized `errorbar` function for myself. But I do not know how to control the `CapSize`, like it is controlled in the default [errorbar](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html); zooming-in or zooming-out does not enlarge the Cap. A simplified version of my code is as follow-

```
function myErrorbar(x, y, h)
for i = 1:length(x)
    y1 = y(i)-h(i);
    y2 = y(i)+h(i);

    x1 = x(i)-0.1*h(i);
    x2 = x(i)+0.1*h(i);
    % errorbar
    line([x(i), x(i)], [y1, y2]); hold on 
    % caps
    line([x1, x2], [y1, y1])
    line([x1, x2], [y2, y2])
end
```

In the above code I have fixed the size of caps equal to 10% of h on either sides. I want to control the capsize like it could be done in the default. The code could be tested with following code

```
x = 1:10:100;
y = [20 30 45 40 60 65 80 75 95 90];
err = 8*ones(size(y));
myErrorbar(x,y,err)
```

Comment: This is a slightly complex question, because you are basically asking how to make a responsive figure. IIRC you'd have to create a listener, which redraws the figure on every zoom-action.

Comment: thanks @Adriaan, this is not something urgent. I am comfortable in using a constant value of `h`.

Comment: When you've got an issue with how something *looks*, it's incredibly helpful if you show an image of how is looks currently, and why that isn't satisfactory, bonus marks if you show a mock up of what you'd like it to look like instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Adriaan mentioned in his comment, this can be achieved by adding a listener to the `XLim` property of the axes to draw to. See the code below and comments for explanation.

The idea is to get the `XLim` after drawing the vertical lines, then determine the width fraction per cap of the axes' `XLim`, and use this to scale the caps accordingly when the `XLim` is changed.

```
function myErrorbar(ax, x, y, err, color)

    % color input argument handling
    if ~exist('color', 'var') || isempty(color)
        color = lines(1); % default lightblue color
    end

    % first plot the vertical lines (so XLim is set to right value)
    y_bot = y - err;
    y_top = y + err;
    % errorbar
    l = line([x; x], [y_bot; y_top], 'color', color);
    hold on

    % get the current XLim
    x_fracs = NaN(size(x)); % variable to store fractions of XLim
    cur_xlim = diff(ax.XLim); % current XLim

    % plot the caps
    x_left = x - 0.1 .* err;
    x_right = x + 0.1 .* err;

    c_top = line([x_left; x_right], [y_top; y_top], 'color', color);
    c_bot = line([x_left; x_right], [y_bot; y_bot], 'color', color);

    % determine width fraction of current x limit
    x_fracs = (x_right - x_left) ./ cur_xlim;

    % add listener for xlim
    addlistener(ax, 'XLim', 'PostGet', @updateCaps);

    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    % callback to update cap width
    function updateCaps(hProperty, eventData)

        % update XLim
        cur_xlim = diff(ax.XLim);

        % determine new cap widths and positions
        cap_width = x_fracs .* cur_xlim;
        x_left = x - 0.5 .* cap_width;
        x_right = x + 0.5 .* cap_width;

        % set cap line x and y data
        for k = 1:length(x)
            c_top(k).XData = [x_left(k), x_right(k)];
            c_bot(k).XData = [x_left(k), x_right(k)];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks @rinkert, I realize that it must have taken sufficient time to make it work. I didn't knew how to deal with `listener`. I am trying to make the function work with `datetime` although I am facing a little difficulty in doing this. I believe, I should be able to resolve it, if not I will respond. Thanks again